# I want to report response time taken by each page via Jmeter, While there are multiple API calls being made on page load. How to do that?

Tags: jmeter, response-time

I am scripting using Jmeter. The Login page calls multiple APIs and then logs in the user and next page that comes is Dashboard. On Dashboard 8 APIs are called. I need to report the response time taken by Login page, Dashboard Page and so on. Currently i am using Transaction Controller which sums up the response time of all requests.

E.g For Dashboard page my script looks like below;

1. Dashboard Transaction Controller

   HTTP request 1
   HTTP request 2
   .
   .
   Http request 8

each request response time is below ~3 sec and all APIs are called parallel by the browser. So Browser usually gives the load time between 3-4 secs. Transaction controller sums up the response time of all 8 Http requests in that and hence i am getting around 18 secs which doesn't comply when browser load time and i check the browser load while executing the load test too and it is always ~3 sec or below.

How to report such page response time as transaction controller is showing the sum of all response times which is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used HTTP Parallel request sampler to solve this. Used Response assertion by selecting option "Sub-Samples only" and add assertions for all http requests and used pattern matching rules as "or" and "Contains"

Answer (score 0):

Use "bzm - Parallel Controller" to send all 8 requests in parallel rather then sequential in current approach.

Comment: I have used parallel controller but it is not fulfilling my requirement. As transaction controller is still adding up the response time of all 8 requests as each request has ~3 secs of response time. How would i know that page loading took how much time. For this i used parallel http request as well and added all http requests in that, it is working fine and now the transaction controller is showing time same as parallel http request which is almost half than before it is now showing avg response time as 3.9 secs which is exactly same when i load page manually during test.

Comment: But now the next problem is to add assertion. As when i add response assertion it is failing. Every request as different response so in response assertion i used "or" and added all options but it failed. I even tried with response code "200" it also failed. :(

Comment: What is your requirement with the assertion? Do you have 8 http samplers? Please share your plan (snapshots) to have a better understanding,